# Como poner la primera letra de la oración y después del punto en mayúscula?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tal como dice en el titulo necesito que en un TextBox la frase me salga de esta manera:

```
"Manzana de oro. Sandia"
```

Estoy trabajando en wpf

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, te sugiero leas la siguiente sección para mejorar la manera en la que preguntas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Es necesario que tus preguntas sean más específicas, quizá publicando código conciso que hayas trabajado y en el cuál te hayas atorado.

Comment: Bueno, ¿Nos muestras que has intentado? Así podemos saber donde podemos ayudarte. Como nuevo colaborador, te recomiendo echarle un ojo al [tour] para que tengas una idea más clara de como funciona el sítio, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para que tu TextBox siempre muestre en mayúscula la letra que siga de un punto tienes varias opciones, un ejemplo sería con un Behaviour, pero creo que lo más fácil sería controlar el evento TextChanged y hacer la modificación al vuelo verificando el contenido con una expresión regular:

**XAML**

```
<TextBox TextChanged="OnTextChanged" />
```

**C#**

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox box = (TextBox)sender;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text) && box.Text.Trim().Length >= 3)
    {
        string expression = @"[\. ]+([a-z])";
        char[] charArray = box.Text.ToCharArray();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(box.Text, expression, RegexOptions.Singleline))
        {
            charArray[match.Groups[1].Index] = Char.ToUpper(charArray[match.Groups[1].Index]);
        }
        string output = new string(charArray);
        box.Text = output;
        box.CaretIndex = box.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

Y ya con eso queda, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa distinta a la de Leodev (evitando Regex) puede ser usando la clase [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) para poder modificar la posición específica del `string` que necesitemos para ponerlo en mayúsculas.

Por lo general, en wpf se busca evitar el codebehind, por lo que te arme un ejemplo directamente en el setter de la propiedad.

```
private string mText;
public string Text 
{
    get => mText;
    set 
    {
        //Instancio un StringBuilder con el texto que recibo como parámetro        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder (value);
        //Por cada letra..
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length - 2; i++) {
            //En caso de que la posición actual sea . y la siguiente un espacio..
            if (sb[i] == '.' && sb[i + 1] == ' ')
                //Implica que el próximo debe estar en mayúsculas.
                sb[i + 2] = char.ToUpper (sb[i + 2]);
        }
        //Por último, efectivamente, guardo el valor en la variable mText.
        mText = sb.ToString ();
    }
}
```

Ahora, simplemente bastaría con setear la propiedad para llegar al resultado que buscas.

Trabajando en C#, bastaría con setear la propiedad

```
TuClase t = new TuClase();
t.Text = "Manzana de oro. sandia";
Console.WriteLine(t.Text);
//Salida Manzana de oro. Sandia
```

Y en caso de que lo bindees en xaml, te recomendaría que uses `UpdateSourceTrigger` en `PropertyChanged` para que el cambio a mayúsculas se vea en tiempo real

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Si usa Binding creo que está super.. tal vez el toque final sería crear un ExtensionMethod con el algoritmo para que sea reutilizable y quedaría de 10.